# iOS: label stops updating when user scrolls through table view

Tags: uitableview, ios7, xcode5

On a view I got a label and a table view. The label gets updated every second through a timer which calls the function that updates the label's text. Now this works all fine. But as soon as a user swipes with his finger on the table view, the label's text stops updating.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Label stops updating when you scroll tableview because both timer and tableView are on the same thread i.e main thread. You can try the below code

**These two Methods are used to update the UILabel irrespective of tableView Scrolling**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

arrData = [NSMutableArray new];

for (int i = 0; i < 150; i ++) {
    [arrData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row number %d",i]];
}

[self performCounterTask];
count = 10;

}


-(void)performCounterTask{

if (count == 0) {
    count = 10;
}

double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    // Your code here

    if (count >= 0) {
        [lblTimer setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)count]];
        count--;

        [self performCounterTask];

    }


});


}
```

**These are the TableView datasource methods**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return arrData.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;

}
```

So, basically you need to keep the Lable updation portion under dispatch queue.

Hope this solution will help you. Happy Coding :)